# nvidia xserver settings freezes when switching between intel and nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime, 18.04

i am using ubuntu 18.04, when switching between intel and nvidia gpu in nvidia prime profile switcher, the application completely freezes, sometimes it shows intel card in use, but actually nvidia card is what ubuntu using , i checked using nvidia-smi. please help.

nvidia driver version 390.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at first, but it turned out the Nvidia Settings program just performs an initramfs and grub update, which can take quite a while. Try to run it in a terminal instead of using the GUI and give it a minute or two.

In command line, you can switch to nvidia with `sudo prime-select nvidia` or to intel with `sudo prime-select intel`.